# How to estimate the heat generation and the power per square cm provided the resistance and the current of a laser diode?

Tags: laser, semiconductor-physics

Laser Diodes are very tiny. So, it is making me confused in its calculation.

In laboratory, the resistance of a laser diode is 10-15 ohm and the current is 80-100 mA.

How could I estimate the heat generation and power per square cm in it?

I could estimate power by the formula $P = I^2 R$, but could it be measured in per square cm? The laser diode is as tiny as in the range of micron.

On the contrary, Heat generation is Energy, but I could find the power. How to get the heat generation? Using formula $E = Pt$, we get an energy directly proportional to time. Is it meant that if we keep the laser diode active for a long time, it would be burned? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: A laser diode doesn't have "a resistance". It has a transfer function that specifies the voltage drop as a function of the current trough the diode. Multiply the two and you have the total power consumption. Subtract the power of the light that it generates and you have the heat that has to be cooled away. For the rest you need to know the geometry of the junction.